# .net MAUI Button command never fired when inside a Grid with a CollectionView

Tags: .net, maui

I'm having a view in my .net Maui project in which I want to add a button calling a certain RelayCommand from my ViewModel, using MVVM CommunityToolkit. However clicking on the button never calls the command (I added a breakpoint inside the function, and it's never reached).

I also tried to use a single Grid, instead of a Grid in a Grid, but it didn't work either. Sometimes hot reload causes it to work temporarily, but when I stop and rerun the app it's still not working.

Edit : A small addition, I completely removed my CollectionViews from my View, for test purposes, and reran the app : the button works, but as soon as I bring my CollectionViews back, I'm back at square one.

My View code :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;assembly=LocalizationResourceManager.Maui"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MatchDirector.ViewModels"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Models;assembly=Models"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:MauiUtils;assembly=MauiUtils"
             x:Class="MatchDirector.GroupsContentPage"
             Title="{lang:Translate Groups}">


    <Grid x:DataType="local:CompetitionViewModel">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Group">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray700}}"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Padding="15, 10" FontSize="32" Text="{Binding .}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>

    <BoxView WidthRequest="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray100}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CollectionView x:Name="CompetitorsCV" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CompetitorsOfGroup}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCompetitor, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Competitor">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray700}}"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Label Padding="15, 10" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="28">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                                    <Span Text=" "/>
                                    <Span Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" >
        <Button Text="Test" Command="{Binding DisqualifySelectedCommand}"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
        

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

My Command from the ViewModel (fairly simple, was just for test purpose) :

```cs
[RelayCommand]
public async Task DisqualifySelected()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    return;
}
```

---

The workaround I found so far, but it's breaking MVVM structure : call manually the function in a Clicked event, in the .cs file associated to the View :

```cs
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (BindingContext is CompetitionViewModel vm)
    {
        vm.DisqualifySelected();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just copy and paste your code and add some test data in viewmodel. it seems that your code works fine (button command can  be fired) on my end. So, could you please share more relevant code such as code-behind and ViewModel or provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? And could you please share the .NET version and platform you use?

Comment: My project is on .net7.0-android. Somehow I'm not able to rerpoduce the issue now I used the solution described below, even when backpaddling to my previous code, I think it somehow misscompiled my code. Thanks for testing it :)

Comment: So glad you solved it! The BindingContext of the Button should inherit from its parent Grid, for which you have set the ```x:DataType="local:CompetitionViewModel"```. So I don't think you need to  set anything for Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course if the `Button` is inside a `CollectionView` the default source for your `Binding` is items in your collection. To fix this, you will need to explicitly set your source back to your `CompetitionViewModel`, for instance:

```xml
<!-- BindingContext is CompetitionViewModel -->
<Collection ItemsSource="...">
    <Collection.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- BindingContext is, implicitly, an item from ItemSource -->
            <!-- Make your Button point back to CompetitionViewModel -->
            <Button Text="Test" Command="{Binding DisqualifySelectedCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:CompetitionViewModel}}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Collection.ItemTemplate>
</Collection>
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

Comment: Actually if you look at my View code, my button isn't inside my CollectionView, just in the same Grid as my CollectionView, they are at the same hierarchical level. In addition, the code was compiling and not rising an error so I guess it could find the Command somewhere.
But it turns out your reply gave me the solution, explicitally setting source with `<Button Text="Test" Command="{Binding DisqualifySelectedCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CompetitionViewModel}}}"/>`fixed the problem, thanks !

Comment: Okay now I made this edit, when I remove it the code works just fine... It seems I had to tell explicitely once to the compiler what the Binding Context was

Comment: Consider using `x:DataType="{x:Type local:CompetitionViewModel}"` for additional validation and performance optimization.